# Is it good catch IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

I have a method m1() which throws IllegalArgumentException. I am invoking this method from some other method called m2, which throws HttpException and Exception.My requirement is that i need to throw HTTPException whenever there is IllegalArgmumentException from m1() while invoking from m2().

The approach i added is as below.Placing the invocation inside try block and if there is any exception then immediately create new HTTP exception and throw it .

```
public static CustomizedEnum m1(String value) {
        if (value == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Input can not be  not be null.");
        }

        if (value.equals("ABC")) return ABC;
        if (value.equals("XYZ")) return xyz;
        if (value.equals("PQR")) return pqr;

        // no matching string, throw an exception
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( value + 
                     " for m2() in CustomizedEnum does not exist."); 
    } 

void m2() throws HttpException,Exception {
   // ..............
   //.................
   //................
  try{
  if(m1("ABC") != null){
  }catch(Exception e){
     throw new HTTPException("Invalid data");
  } 
     // ............
     //................   
}
```

Would like to know is this above approach is best approach or not. If this approach is not good one please suggest some better approach.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to simply catch ```Exception```. Use multiple catch statements ```catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { ... }```

Comment: If you're expecting IllegalArgumentException, you should catch that specifically, not any Exception.

Comment: @BillK *"Rules are for the obedience of fools and the guidance of wise men."* (D. Bader). It's good to state "Never catch `Exception`" as a rule. You'll notice soon enough when you're encountering one of the *few* places where catching `Exception` is the right thing to do, and here, it is certainly *not* the right thing. (I've seen code with three levels of nested `catch (Exception e)` blocks... that's fun...)

Comment: @Marco13 There are two very different use cases for exception, both are very important. There is the low level, checked style exception handling (which is what you are talking about), and there is the high level unchecked "How do we deal with unexpected stuff" level. The high level should probably be there in most apps (at the top of all threads) and it should probably catch Exception or Throwable. Without the try/catch your app might just stop processing, no warning! If you put a try/catch/log inside your main loop and it not only tells you what's going on but successfully resumes work.

Comment: @BillK You should not (knowingly) **do** something that causes an exception. The fact that many APIs don't (expliciltly) state things like "Throws NPE if called with `null" is no justification for *catching* an NPE, for that matter.

Comment: @Marco13 I've been using NonNull annotations with Intellij for a lot of that type of checking.  You can "Annotate" external/library apis so a lot of time it comes down to tracing through their code a little to prove how nulls will behave or if it can return a null then annotating it appropriately, then if you chase the annotations through the rest of your code you eliminate the biggest source of exceptions altogether.  Still need the high-level catch (throwable) though.

Answer (score 2):

A general rule of thumb is to only catch exceptional exceptions.  Essentially this means to catch only the exceptions you can't expect, otherwise you need to prevent them with logic.

Also, you should catch specific exceptions, rather than a generic `Exception`. If you don't know what exception you're catching, it's probably a sign that you should try to figure out why an exception is happening in the first place and try to prevent it.

The idea behind catching an exception is to prevent the code from crashing and quitting execution, as well as trying to recover from the error, with logging the error so the developer can try to fix the error in later versions (if possible).

You shouldn't be throwing an error unless you expect to handle it somewhere else in the code. Otherwise you are causing a crash that should be otherwise addressed.

Some exceptions can't be avoided, though. This can be from an interrupted network connection, corrupt file stream, out of memory, and plenty of others reasons. You should still try to prevent them, but it's not always possible.

The following link describes the conditions for, why, and how to catch exceptions better than I can.

https://stackabuse.com/exception-handling-in-java-a-complete-guide-with-best-and-worst-practices/

Comment: Just a note: not all errors are meant to be handled. Sometimes I just want my application to crash (it's totally fine for a typical Cron job to crash and report the error) or my service call to fail because I detected an invalid state that should not have occurred (malformed JSON, concurrent modifications to a non thread-safe collection etc)

Comment: @Dici, if you are report/logging an error, then you are still catching the error. Just because you aren't trying to recover from it, it doesn't mean you aren't trying to do something after the error happens, such as trying to fail more gracefully than a dead stop. Sure, not all exceptions can be caught or recovered from, but that still doesn't mean you shouldn't try to prevent it. Not handling an exception should be an exception.

Comment: Meh, I don't know, I have worked for some time on batch computing systems and we were completely fine propagating exceptions to the top to get notified that something was wrong (the job ran out of memory, a required field was missing from the data). There was just no way to continue the computation in these cases, and since a Cron job doesn't serve any request it can just wake up and die whenever it wants. In our services of course, we'd never do that, but it really depends what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a strange differentiation, but it isn't bad as long as the string you are passing is coming from code and not from user input.

The general idea is that you shouldn't ever use an exception as part of your program flow--in other words, you should be pretty sure you'll never get that exception unless you write bad code.

So if it's user input or coming from external data then you should manually check your values before calling that function, but throwing the exception is not a bad safety check to tell you (as a programmer) that you've done something wrong in development. When used in this way, you should use unchecked exceptions because you don't really have to even catch them--in fact you probably shouldn't!  Just let it crash your program with a stack trace so you can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Following Bill K's comment, I agree that in your case you are probably using exceptions as control-flow, which isn't a great idea:

- exceptions are made for errors, not conditional branching. You most often don't want to recover from an exception (by recover I mean continue as if nothing happened), at best you want your application to survive i.e. not crash, that's pretty common if it's a service or an app.
- exceptions are a lot slower than if/else branching
- it's just verbose

Now I want to make a larger point about exception handling because it is possible that `m1` throws an exception that you had not foreseen initially, and if `m2` is exposed to external clients you probably don't want them to see random errors from your service. That's why I would add a "catch-all" and rethrow as a more general error such as `InternalFailure`.

Furthermore, don't forget to always include the root cause of an exception when you rethrow it, otherwise you'll have a hard time figuring out what happened exactly:

```
throw new HTTPException("Invalid data", e);
```

The last problem in your code is that you're catching all exceptions as if they were necessarily about "invalid data", even though it might not be the case. You will therefore generate a confusing exception.

If we compile all those observations, it would give us something like that:

```
validateInputs(inputs);

try {
    if(m1(inputs) != null) { ... }
} catch (Throwable t) {
   String msg = "Call failed for inputs ...");
   log.error(msg, t); // log for service owner to investigate
   // InternalFailure(msg, t) if you don't mind passing the exact exceptions to clients, but I'd say it's not necessary
   throw new InternalFailure(msg);
}

private static void validateInputs(Inputs inputs) {
    if (notValid(inputs)) throw new HTTPException("Invalid data: " + inputs); 
}
```

That way, you are not mixing completely unrelated things with a "bad data" message, and you're still offering a clean API with only a known set of expected exceptions that could result from calling this method.

Comment: Still bad, don't use exceptions to control program flow, so even catching specific exceptions isn't going to fix this.

Comment: I think it would be better to catch Exception instead of Throwable in the final catch clause, you probably don't want to catch all throwables like OutOfMemoryError at this level and then rethrow them as some custom exceptions

Comment: @BillK it's not controlling flow, right? It's just exception decoration, it's pretty common. I guess it the OP's case perhaps you're right that it's easier to just check all inputs upstream. However, I'm making a larger point about potential runtime exceptions being thrown in business logic and how the top-level service endpoint which is exposed to external callers should handle it. I'll see if I can change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @KamilPiwowarski yeah, a bit debatable. If this method is directly called from outside customers (which I assumed), I don't think they need to know my service is out of memory, they just need to know there was an internal failure that was not caused by their request.

Comment: At the top level of any thread program loop it's very important to catch Throwable.  If you don't, threads tend to eat the exception invisibly and just die which is a real pain. In your "Main" thread on a trivial app it's not important to catch anything, just let it throw out and crash your app (fail early, fail visibly!)  This answer is a good example of the try/catch you should have running inside a threads main looping construct.

Comment: @Dici as you said, it's debatable, as it always depends on the use case. In case of customer facing service (I assume web-service) we could try handling it somehow in the app code, but we can as well allow the app to fail and map the error to some error page on, for example, nginx level. Regardless of method used, I agree external customers should see some generic internal error message in such cases.

Comment: Ah yeah fair enough, it can depend on the framework you're using I guess. I have developed in context where annotations were available to define exception mappings in the context of service calls, so we were just able to let things propagate and be mapped. What Bill says is a bit different and is correct, for example when passing a `Runnable` to a scheduled thread pool, I always make sure the `Runnable` can never throw any exception, otherwise it will kill the scheduled thread silently and it will not restart.

Comment: Good changes, @Dici!